# What is Temperature of an object?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

When we say "body temperature", "room temperature", or "temperature of an object", we say it by 1 number ($25^{\circ}$ C, etc.). By ***Newton's Cooling law*** we can derive an ODE for heat conduction on an object, say $T(t)$ as the temperature of that object at time $t$:

$$ T'(t) = -K(T(t) - T_\text{environment}), \:\: t>0, K>0 $$

assuming $T_\text{environment}$ to be constant all the time.

---

**In contrast**, a solution to a 1D Heat equation that models a horizontal rod can be $T(x,t)$, which means temperature can vary along the horizontal rod. Furthermore, if we model heat dynamics on a plate we can use $T(x,y,t)$.

---

So what is temperature? In the ODE case does $T(t)$ mean the average heat energy throughout the mass of the object?

Comment: Many bodies do not have a constant temperature. But if it is close enough (as in “body temperature”) it doesn’t matter enough to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Newton's law of cooling, it is assumed that conduction within the object is so fast (compared with convective heat transfer from the object to the surroundings) that, within the object, the temperature is spatially uniform.  On the other hand, in the transient heat conduction equation, it is assumed that the temperature within the object varies with spatial position (which gives rise to conductive heat flow within the object).

Answer (score -1):

Temperature is a unit of measurement which gives a statistical quantity of the kinetic and potential energy of particles in a system. The only difference between heat and temperature would be that temperature is an averaged quantity while heat is the total sum. Newton's law where $T$ is the average of the hot and cold end, if you consider it to be the $T \left( x , t \right)$ varying with $x$, you'll get the answer close to the approximation of averaging.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Heat is a form of energy. Temperature (by definition in the Clausius form of the second law of thermodynamics) is that which determines the direction of heat flow. Heat is an extrinsic, temperature is an intrinsic physical quantity. Internal energy of a system is always well defined (at least until we get to gravitating systems) while temperature is only well defined in the equilibrium limit.

Comment: @FlatterMann saying that temperature determines which direction heat flow would be partially true in the context of differentiating between heat and temperature since when you talk about heat, you usually mean flow of heat.

Comment: @HarshdeepChhabra When I talk about heat I am talking about a form of internal energy. When I talk about temperature I talk about heat flow. They are not the same thing, just as position and velocity are not the same thing.